# How to use file_get_contents() with non-English symbols in URL?

Tags: php, url, unicode, file-get-contents

I'm getting this error when I try to access non-English (Unicode) URLs using PHP's `file_get_contents()` function. The URL was: http://ml.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B4%B2%E0%B4%AF%E0%B4%A3%E0%B5%BD_%E0%B4%AE%E0%B5%86%E0%B4%B8%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%B8%E0%B4%BF

I've got this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://ml.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B4%B2%E0%B4%AF%E0%B4%A3%E0%B5%BD_%E0%B4%AE%E0%B5%86%E0%B4%B8%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%B8%E0%B4%BF) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden..
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in G:\xampp\htdocs\codes\htmlParse1.php on line 8

Is there any restriction for the `file_get_contents()` function? Does it only accept English URLs?

Comment: @viakondratiuk what are you trying to say? The above URL is already URLencoded. Weird... the URL works in the browser, and I can't see a reason why it shouldn't. Does it work for plain URLs?

Comment: @Pekka: yes, ascii-URLs work OK... weird

Comment: What language is that? My browser can't even display those characters correctly...

Comment: This is my native language Malayalam, South Indian. That doesn't even matter. It's all unicode!

Comment: @Calle: exactly as Jenson said, it doesn't matter - neither does Slovak work. Try sk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Žuvačka

Comment: I can get sv.wikipedia.org or en.wikipedia.org without any changes to the user agent (as a solution below suggests). I'm just throwing something out there:
sv.wikipedia.org works, en.wikipedia.org works but ml.wikipedia.org doesn't work? Why? Well, ml.wikipedia.org redirects to a URL which is not URL encoded (at least doesn't appear so in the browser), could such redirects cause problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing header information like user agent. I would advice you just use Just use `curl`

```
$url = 'http://ml.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B4%B2%E0%B4%AF%E0%B4%A3%E0%B5%BD_%E0%B4%AE%E0%B5%86%E0%B4%B8%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%B8%E0%B4%BF';
$ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://ml.wikipedia.org");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print($data);
```

[Live CURL Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pHyKpN)

If you must use `file_get_content`

```
$options = array(
        'http'=>array(
                'method'=>"GET",
                'header'=>"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" .
                "Cookie: centralnotice_bucket=0-4.2; clicktracking-session=M7EcNiC2Zcuko7exVGUvLfdwxzSK3Boap; narayam-scheme=ml\r\n" . 
                "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17"
        )
);


$url = 'http://ml.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B4%B2%E0%B4%AF%E0%B4%A3%E0%B5%BD_%E0%B4%AE%E0%B5%86%E0%B4%B8%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%B8%E0%B4%BF';
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $file ;
```

[Live file_get_content Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QMExaE)

Answer (score 1):

If there is a `403 Forbidden`, the connection should work.
That's just a warning, that the webserver responded with the status code 403. Wikipedia denies downloading without valid user agent:

> Scripts should use an informative User-Agent string with contact information, or they may be IP-blocked without notice.

The second error should be from the next lines that are handling the result (a String object) of your `file_get_contents(...)` call.

**Edit:** You should try setting your user agent with e.g. `ini_set('user_agent', 'wikiPHP');` before doing the request. That should work fine.

Comment: Nope, just checked it on my own PHP server, no data are sent to wikipedia servers at all.

Comment: Tried with user agent, Still didn't resolve for this Indic language..:(

Comment: I Tried with Baba's Code. Worked! Thanks @baba,  FurloSK, nlsbshtr. Cheers..:)